# Flask SQLAlchemy, IntegrityError, ForeignKeyViolation - Creating relationships between tables

Tags: postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a Flask app where I can return a list of 'workspaces' from a postgresql database, a list of 'categories and a list of 'projects'.

In projects.py, when a GET method is called, the database will return all of the 'workspaces' and all of the 'categories' and get both the `id` and `name` for each, I can then put this in a dropdown button for the user to select. This part of the code works fine.

When a POST method is called, this should add a new row to the 'projects' table to define a new project, along with this should be the `workspace_id` and the `categories_id` that the user selected.

This part of the code is not working, I get the following error message:

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation) insert or update on table "projects" violates foreign key constraint "workspace_id"
> DETAIL: Key (id)=(19) is not present in table "workspaces".

> [SQL: INSERT INTO projects (name, description, category_id, workspace_id, visibility_level, slug) VALUES (%(name)s, %(description)s, %(category_id)s, %(workspace_id)s, %(visibility_level)s, %(slug)s) RETURNING projects.id]
> [parameters: {'name': 'Brand New Project', 'description': 'gfhfghfg', 'category_id': '1', 'workspace_id': '1', 'visibility_level': '1', 'slug': 'brand-new-project'}]

models.py:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from taskmanagement.database import Base

class Projects(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'projects'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(140), unique=True)
    description = Column(String(140), unique=True)
    category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('categories.id'), unique=False, nullable=False)
    category = relationship('Categories', lazy=True, uselist=False, primaryjoin="Categories.id == Projects.category_id")
    workspace_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('workspaces.id'), unique=False, nullable=False)
    workspace = relationship('Workspaces', lazy=True, uselist=False, primaryjoin="Projects.workspace_id == Workspaces.id")
    visibility_level = Column(Integer, unique=False)
    slug = Column(String(240), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, name=None, description=None, category_id=None, workspace_id=None, visibility_level=None, slug=None):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.category_id = category_id
        self.workspace_id = workspace_id
        self.visibility_level = visibility_level
        self.slug = slug

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Projects {self.name!r}>'

class Workspaces(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'workspaces'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Workspaces {self.name!r}>'

class Categories(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'categories'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Workspaces {self.name!r}>'
```

Projects.py

```
@projects.route('/projects/add', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def project_add():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        categories = Categories.query.all()
        workspaces = Workspaces.query.all()
        categories_results = [
            {
                "id": category.id,
                "name": category.name
            } for category in categories]
        workspaces_results = [
            {
                "id": workspace.id,
                "name": workspace.name
            } for workspace in workspaces]

        results =  {"categories": categories_results, "workspaces": workspaces_results}
        return render_template('project_add.html', title='Add Project', results=results)
    else:
        name = request.form['project_name']
        slug = request.form['project_slug']
        description = request.form['project_desc']
        visibility_level = request.form['project_visibility']
        category_id = request.form['category_id']
        workspace_id = request.form['workspace_id']

        form_results = {
                "name": request.form['project_name'],
                "slug": request.form['project_slug'],
                "description": request.form['project_desc'],
                "visibility_level": request.form['project_visibility'],
                "category_id": request.form['category_id'],
                "workspace_id": int(request.form['workspace_id'])
            }


        #return form_results

        results = Projects(name, description, category_id, workspace_id, visibility_level, slug)
        db_session.add(results)
        db_session.commit()
```

I'm completely stuck of this problem. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are the two error messages from the same event?  I don't see 19 anywhere in the second message.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).